# in R, using data.table package, how to do a subset with special variable(with space)

Tags: r, data.table

I am reading a txt file with data.table package.

```
df<- fread("df.txt")
head(df)
Number Region Type Car ...
     1       1       1
     2       1       2
     3       1       1  
     4       1       1
     5       2       2
     6       2       3
```

I would like to do a subset of df with the Type Car iqual to 1 and 3. When I write something like this

```
>class(df)
"data.table" "data.frame"
>subset(df, Type Car %in% c(1,3))
```

This does not work. Some solution?

Comment: I'm surprised your data reads in at all. `fread` has no way of knowing that the two words "Type" and "Car" are to be tied together for a single column name (assuming you copy-pasted part of your txt file here).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got a data table from `fread()` (unless you used `data.table = FALSE`), so you can use data table row subsetting instead of `subset()`.  Since you have a multi-word column name, you will need to apply back-ticks around it.

```
df[`Type Car` %in% c(1, 3)]
```

The same goes for `subset()` if you choose to use it.  In fact, back-ticks will always be necessary when referencing multi-word names that contain spaces.  It would be better to use qualified R names.  You can reset the names with

```
setnames(df, make.names(names(df), unique = TRUE))
```

so you can avoid the back-ticks.  Then you could do

```
df[Type.Car %in% c(1, 3)]
```

**Note:** In *data.table* version 1.9.6, you can now name the columns in `fread()` with the `col.names` argument.  As Michael Chirico has mentioned, it's best to get this problem out of the way immediately.

Comment: Also, do yourself a favor and `setnames` away those spaces ASAP, unless you really only need the table briefly.